# vectorImages isnt working with bottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, xml, svg, bottomnavigationview

I add an `svgFile` in my drawable file and implement it in `bottomNavigationView` but the picture is invisible.
[image]

> update. I solve my problem.

I notice that not all `vectorImages` is working see this links for more.
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#svg

For working vector images visit this link. https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material+Symbols

Comment: can you show us your layout code

Comment: Did you convert your svg to a vector drawable as described in the article you linked? Does Android Studio show any warnings when you preview it?

Comment: @SergeiKozelko yes i convert it and it work well.